# Using Next.js '@/' imports with Storybook

Tags: next.js, storybook, next.js13

I am using Storybook 7.4 in a Next.js 13.4 project. When trying to run Storybook, I get the following type of error for my imported components:

> ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/stores/settings.store' in...

Here's the import causing it:

`import { useSettingsStore } from '@/stores/settings.store';`

This `@/` syntax comes out of the box with Next.js. But Storybook doesn't seem to understand it.

I am aware that I can replace `@/` with the actual path to the component to solve the error. However, I would prefer if there was a way to get Storybook to understand this import syntax, since it is a lot more convenient.

Is it possible to configure Storybook to understand this?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution in the docs under [TypeScript modules are not resolved within Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/webpack#typescript-modules-are-not-resolved-within-storybook)

For Next.js `@/` imports to work, ensure your `.storybook/main.ts` file contains the following:

```
// .storybook/main.ts
import path from 'path';
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/nextjs";

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  framework: '@storybook/nextjs',
  stories: ['../src/**/*.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    if (config.resolve) {
      config.resolve.alias = {
        ...config.resolve.alias,
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      };
    }
    return config;
  },
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who is getting similar error in Next14 using app directory (without src), add the following code to `.storybook/main.ts` instead.

```
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  ...
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    ...
    if (config && config.resolve && config.resolve.alias) {
       config.resolve.alias = {
         ...config.resolve.alias,
         '@': resolve(__dirname, '../'),
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Next14, typescript, and tailwindcss. `.storybook/main.ts`

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/nextjs"
import * as path from 'path'
import { Configuration } from 'webpack'

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: [
    "../stories/**/*.mdx",
    "../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)",
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/addon-styling-webpack",
    ({
      name: "@storybook/addon-styling-webpack",

      options: {
        rules: [{
          test: /\.css$/,
          sideEffects: true,
          use: [
            require.resolve("style-loader"),
            {
              loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
              options: {

                importLoaders: 1,
              },
            }, {
              loader: require.resolve("postcss-loader"),
              options: {
                implementation: require.resolve("postcss"),
              },
            },
          ],
        },],
      }
    }),

  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/nextjs",
    options: {
      nextConfigPath: path.resolve(__dirname, "../next.config.js"),
    },
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
  webpackFinal: (config: Configuration) => {
    const { module, resolve } = config ?? {}
    if (module?.rules && resolve?.alias) {
      resolve.alias = {
        ...resolve.alias,
        '@': [
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
        ]
      }
      resolve.roots = [
        path.resolve(__dirname, '../public'),
        'node_modules'
      ]
    }
    return config
  }
}
export default config
```